# What is the most inclusive exercise that does not require tools?

Tags: exercise, muscle

By most incluse I refer to activating the most muscle groups. The background of my question is the following thought:

> If you had to choose one single exercise to do every day, which one
>   would it be because it activates the most muscle groups?

Comment: I submit that there is none, because you can string together any set of movements, and call it "one rep". For instance I'd do a squat + jump-to-bar + muscle-up + bar-dip + L-sit + L-sit-twist and so on, and so forth.

Comment: And I'm not being cheeky. Stringing together movements into one exercise is one of the foundations of how gymnasts gain their impressive-as-hell physiques.

Comment: @alec good point, perhaps a better question would be what are the minimum exercises to work every main muscle group

Comment: That sounds like a pretty good question, yeah.

Comment: Good point! Do you want me to change the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest 2. Push-ups and squads.

Pushups works: chest, shoulders and triceps. Mainly focused on chest. And this exercice have many variants.

Squads: low-back and quadriceps.

These 2 exercices can be done at home.

Both are excelent fat burnners

Comment: None of these target biceps, upper back, lats. Essentially, there are no pulling movements here.

Comment: He asked for most inclusive exercices. No for any routine.

Comment: Agreed, but why squads? (And I assume you mean squats.) If he's asking for one single exercise, shouldn't we be a bit more inclusive? For instance, a burpee does a squat, and more.

Comment: He asked for one and I said 2. I wanted to propuse 2 easy and complete exercices that could be done at home, with no weights nor machines :-). And yes I wanted to say squats :-D. Excuse my english. And agree. Burpees is an excelent exercice. It can be done with pushups and it become even better. Good point.